# Cannot connect to mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

So I've installed mongo using home brew and I've installed it through npm, so I have the JS driver.

When I run mongo in command line though, I get this -

```
 MongoDB shell version: 2.2.2
connecting to: test
Thu Jan 24 02:38:26 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:91
exception: connect failed
```

why is that happening?

Comment: Have you started the mongod process running in another terminal window?

Comment: Are you running mongod on another machine? Check your firewall...

Comment: oh no I'm not - how do I do that?

Comment: oh wait- is that just running mongod command?

Comment: can either of you explain why I need to do that?

Comment: OSX - running mongod and then mongo worked - but why?

Comment: could be the daemon had not started on install?

Comment: You have to run mongod first because the database server needs to be up and running in order for the mongo shell to access it. Mongod accesses localhost by default.

Answer (score 1):

After you've installed MongoDB, open a terminal window and go to the file path where your MongoDB application is stored e.g c:\MongoDB. Then type mongod and hit enter. This should start this process running. Mongod is the database server that you then access via the mongo shell.

After mongod is running, open a new terminal window and type mongo then hit enter. You should now be up and running. You can test that it's working by typing the following into the mongo shell as an example:

```
>
>db.names.save({'name':"James"})
>db.names.find()
```

This should then return the document you have just saved to the database as shown in the example below.

```
>{"_id" ObjectID:"764tdf763dyf6337fd376","name":"James"}
```

Read through the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/) and look for tutorials online. 10gen have just started an [excellent online course](https://education.10gen.com/). It's free and started this week so you might still be able to register.