# mongo connection failed when I have made connection through pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am using this for insertion:

```
import pymongo
import sys

def main():
    connection = pymongo.Connection("mongodb://localhost", safe=True)

    db = connection.m101
    people = db.people

    person ={'name': 'Barack Obama', 'role':'President',
             'address':{'address1': 'The White House',
                        'street': '1600 Pensylvania Avenue',
                        'state':'DC',
                        'city':'Washington'},
             'interests':['government', 'basketball', 'the middle east']

        }

    people.insert(person)
```

And when I try to use writing `mongo` command it says

```
Could not connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 src/mongo
shell mongo.js:91
exception: connection failed
```

What can be done? I am following their tutorial!

Comment: Is MongoDB actually running and listening on localhost?

Comment: See here for more information  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14499277/cannot-connect-to-mongodb#comment20209093_14499277

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run mongo daemon server.

$ mongod

You can look more information here:
[Is mongodb running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091624/is-mongodb-running)